# How can I click on a class within a form using selenium

Tags: angularjs, forms, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a test case that clicks on an email and password field. The tricky part is that these fields are inside a form, so I tried with xpath, cssSelector, and even partialLinkText and Selenium still doesn't find the element.

This is the code of the page:

```
<form class="well form-inline ng-pristine ng-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-submit="login()" ng-hide="loggedInUser">
         <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required" ng-model="user.email" val="Your email" placeholder="Email" required="" type="text"/>
         <input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" ng-model="user.password" val="password" placeholder="Password" type="password"/>
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Log in</button>
</form>
```

I've tried with:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class = 'ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required']"));

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@ng-model = 'user.password']"));

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-invalid ng-invalid-required"));
```

None of them work.

Comment: it's better to use 'www.protractortest.org' for Angularjs. Protractor make testing more Easy. and u can find element using ng-model

Comment: Have you tried using `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[ng-model='user.email']"))`? Maybe this could work.

Comment: The issue here is Selenium is unable to identify an unique element with those specific xpath. A solution to your problem could be to to start looking for those "email" & "password" field from certain tags in the HTML DOM a bit higher up where you can find a distinct id of an element and then traverse down the DOM to identify these elements.

Comment: Have you checked if this form is inside an iframe?

Comment: @Tom That selector worked perfectly! Thanks!